# quadratic formula function python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a fuction that solves for the roots of a quadratic formula and return them as a list. I need to make sure parameters are numbers aswell. It also has to solve for a root when a = 0.

```
def quadratic_roots(a, b, c):

  if type(a) != float and int:
      print('All values must be a int or float. Bitch')
      return None
  if type(b) != float and int:
      print('All values must be a int or float. Bitch')
      return None
  if type(c) != float and int:
      print('All values must be a int or float. Bitch')
      return None

  else:
      if a == 0:
          root = (-c) / b
          list_root = [root]
          return list_root

      elif a == 0 and b == 0:
          empty = []
          return empty

      elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 0:
          empty = []
          return empty

      else:
          discriminant = (b ** 2) -  4  * a * c
          root1 = ((-b) - ((discriminant)**.5))/(2*a)
          root2 = ((-b) + ((discriminant)**.5))/(2*a)
          if root1 > root2:
              list_roots = [root2, root1]
              return list_roots
          elif root2 > root1:
              list_roots = [root1, root2]
              return list_roots
          elif root1 == root2:
              list_roots = [root1]
              return list_roots
```

Comment: What problems are you having?  What is your question?

Comment: solve for roots and problem im having is that it says when i run quadratic_roots(1, 2, 3), it treats them not as an int/float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues:

- The check for float or int was not correct.
- The case where the answer is -c/b is not just when a == 0.  It is when a is 0 and neither b nor c is 0.  That check needs to happen first.
- It doesn't break the program, but nested if/elif/else don't serve a point when you always return from the if. In that case an elif is just an if at the higher level.
- If you don't covert your operands to floats and you are using python 2 and you have the case of -c/b, then if these are ints, you are going to get the integer division answer and not the correct floating point answer.
- You aren't handling imaginary roots.  I don't know what you wanted to do there, so I didn't handle them either.  Just know that this code doesn't handle the case where the discriminant is negative.

Here's my take on the code:

```
def quadratic_roots(a, b, c):

  if type(a) != float and type(a) != int:
      print('All values must be a int or float. Bitch')
      return None
  if type(b) != float and type(b) != int:
      print('All values must be a int or float. Bitch')
      return None
  if type(c) != float and type(c) != int:
      print('All values must be a int or float. Bitch')
      return None

  a = float(a)
  b = float(b)
  c = float(c)
  if a == 0 and (b == 0 or c == 0):
    return []
  if a == 0:
      root = (-c) / b 
      list_root = [root]
      return list_root

  discriminant = (b ** 2) -  4  * a * c 
  root1 = ((-b) - ((discriminant)**.5))/(2*a)
  root2 = ((-b) + ((discriminant)**.5))/(2*a)
  if root1 > root2:
      list_roots = [root2, root1]
  elif root2 > root1:
      list_roots = [root1, root2]
  else: # roots are equal
      list_roots = [root1]
  return list_roots
```